# making iFrame scrollable in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fullpage.js

i made a Website with fullpage.js and on 2 sites a need to use a iFrame. But when i hover over the iframe section i can´t scroll. On another site i have the same issue without fullpage.js

Is there any fix for this? I need to interact with the iframe but only with clicks, not with the mousewheel. It should also work in responsive mode

here are the 2 sites:

http://wordpress.p587350.webspaceconfig.de/produktvisualisierung/
On this one the 2 products are embeded via a iFrame

http://wordpress.p587350.webspaceconfig.de/360-rundgaenge/
On this one the second slide is a iFrame

Comment: [Don't post links to your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), post enough code so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's a browser restriction. Scroll events can't be detected on iframes if they belong to an external source. Therefore fullPage.js can't know if you are scrolling or not.